# mongodb query script by js. with condition as an array to iterate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
    db = db.getSiblingDB("aqua") //same as use otherdb
    var legalStatus=["initiate","process","complete","replicating","failed","offline_complete","offline_fail","invalid"];
    var replicas=db.aquaObject.find({"replicas":{$ne:null},"replicas.status":{$nin:legalStatus}});
    replicas.forEach(
function(t){
    db.aquaObject.update(t,{$set:{"replicas.0.status":"initiate"}});
});
```

this is the script that I wrote. But the condition in the find method: `"replicas.status"`,here the `replicas` is an array. I want to iterator all the replicas and filter each one's status. So I believe what I write is not correct. How can I refine it? Thanks.

Comment: In your forEach block, for each document, why don't you iterate over all the 'replica.status' for that document and then construct a single update query and then do the update ?

Let me know if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar because the `replicas` property is an array. I need to iterate over each replica of each aquaObject document. `status` is an attribute of each replica. But I already figured out the solution that I can use the `$elemMatch` to do the filter job. Like this: `var objects=db.aquaObject.find({"replicas":{$ne:null},"replicas":{$elemMatch:{"status":{$nin:legalStatus}}}});`